# vertical spacing of frametitle in various scenarios

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Occasionally, my frametitle requires a line break and occasionally there is a framesubtitle. I'm trying to control the vertical spacing in each of these scenarios.  It's easy with a framesubtitle (just check to see if it is empty and adjust the space as necessary). However, how can I determine how many lines (or vertical space) are required for the frametitle text?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx} % to define table width
\usepackage{calc}     % to add and subtract lengths

\newdimen\leftlogosize
\newdimen\rightlogosize
\def\leftlogo{Physics_Logo.png}
\def\rightlogo{SanJac_Logo.png}
\newdimen\logolength
\leftlogosize=1.2cm
\rightlogosize=1.2cm
\logolength=1.5cm

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip 0.2cm%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,vmode]{frametitle}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}{L{\logolength} @{\hskip 0pt}Z @{\hskip 0pt} R{\logolength}}
      \includegraphics[height=\leftlogosize]{\leftlogo} &%
      \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        \vskip-1cm%
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\centering\insertframetitle\strut\par%
      \else%
        \vskip-1cm%
        \usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\centering\insertframetitle\strut\par%
        \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\centering\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi%
      \vskip -2ex%
      \centering\noindent\rule{\paperwidth-\logolength-\logolength-24pt}{.5pt} &% the 24 pt is for the default tabularx spacing for the logos
      \hfill%
      \includegraphics[height=\rightlogosize]{\rightlogo} \\% 
    \end{tabularx}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title \\ with a line break}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \framesubtitle{\Large with a sub title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title \\ with a line break}
  \framesubtitle{\Large with a sub title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, the question was edited to add a complete mwe.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! And what alignment do you want for the different cases?

Comment: @samcarter - for a title with no subtitle: \vskip-.7cm for a title with a line break and no subtitle: \vskip-1.2cm for a title with a subtitle: \vskip-1.1cm for a title with a line break and a subtitle: \vskip-1.3cm –